# Create heatmap and output to raster or shapefile

Tags: python, postgis, heat-map, geoplot

I am trying to create heatmap with `spatial data` to display on `GeoServer`. Please note that it should be smooth by some `kernel density estimations` and not a simple count.

Looks like the [geoplot.kdeplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html) and [seaborn.kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) can be used to generate heatmaps and save as images.

But is there a way to generate `shapefiles` or `raster files` as outputs that can be used on GeoServer?

Any other suggestions that can be implemented with `postgis` and `python`? The dataset is quite large.

Comment: In which format comes your dataset? Is already a table in a postgres database?

Comment: Yes I've imported the CSV files to postrgres.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration that GeoServer can consume directly from postgres you could do a workflow in the database itself, there is no kernel density estimations function in postgres but it has been solved here https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2894#no1. Where I took this code with some slight adaptations in the execution section:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __kde(bandwidth double precision, rast raster)
  RETURNS raster AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
xcorner double precision;
ycorner double precision;
resolutionx double precision;
resolutiony double precision;
width double precision;
height double precision; 
ynew double precision;
xnew double precision;
kde_value double precision;
kde_matrix double precision[];
srid integer;
distance double precision[];
point_value integer[];
length integer;
kde_term double precision;
query character varying;
constant double precision;
BEGIN
SELECT ST_UpperLeftX(rast) INTO xcorner;
SELECT ST_UpperLeftY(rast) INTO ycorner;
SELECT ST_ScaleX(rast) INTO resolutionx;
SELECT ST_ScaleY(rast) INTO resolutiony;
SELECT ST_Width(rast) into width;
SELECT ST_Height(rast) into height;
SELECT ST_Srid(rast) into srid;
xcorner=xcorner + resolutionx/2;
ycorner=ycorner + resolutiony/2;
constant = 3/(pi()*power(bandwidth, 2))*1000000;
FOR j in 0..height-1 LOOP
    ynew=ycorner+j*resolutiony;
    FOR i in 0..width-1 LOOP
        xnew=xcorner+i*resolutionx;
        SELECT 
        array_agg(
            st_distance(
                st_setsrid(
                    st_wkttosql(
                        'POINT('||xnew||' '||ynew||')'
                    ), 
                srid),
            geom)
        ), array_agg(value)
        INTO distance, point_value
        FROM kde_points
        WHERE st_intersects(
            st_buffer(
                st_setsrid(
                    st_wkttosql(
                        'POINT('||xnew||' '||ynew||')'
                    ), srid
                ), bandwidth
            ), geom
        );      
        SELECT array_length(point_value, 1 ) into length;
        kde_value=0;        
        IF length IS NOT NULL THEN
            FOR k in 1..length LOOP
                ------- CHOICE OF KDE FUNCTION
                kde_term = point_value[k]*constant*power(1-power(distance[k]/bandwidth, 2), 2);
                ------- 
                kde_value:=kde_value+kde_term;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
        kde_matrix[i]=kde_value;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT ST_SetValues(rast, 1, 1, j+1, kde_matrix) into rast; 
END LOOP;
RETURN rast;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100;
```

How to execute

```
-- Create the table that will contain the Kernel Density Estimation raster
DROP table if exists raster_table;

create table raster_table(
    rid serial,
    rast raster,
    CONSTRAINT raster_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rid)
);

-- Create an empty raster
insert into raster_table (rast)
(select st_makeemptyraster(800, 500, <upper left x>, <upper left y>, 100, -100, 0, 0, <srid>));

-- Add a band to the empty raster
UPDATE raster_table
SET rast = ST_AddBand(rast, 1, '32BF', 0, 0) where rid=1;

-- Create a tempory table with KDE input points. The table has to be called "kde_points". The geometry column has to be called "geom" and the value of a point has to be called "count"
-- In this case, a point values is the number of data points which are snapped to a grid (10 meters resolution). Indeed, it makes the KDE operation faster. 
-- You can use the point values for a weighted KDE if you want.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kde_points;
DROP index IF EXISTS kde_points_index;

create table kde_points as(
select sum(some_value) as value, ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 10) as geom 
from points 
where geom is not null
group by geom
);

create index kde_points_index on kde_points USING gist(geom);
-- Create the Kernel Density Estimation raster
-- First parameter is the bandwidth
-- Second parameter is the raster column
update raster_table set rast= __kde(1500, rast) where rid=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pepe. I do not have a column for 'some_value' can I just use a dummy column with value 1?

Comment: Of course, you can adapt it to your needs and use any aggregation function with any value column, that's just a usage example.